# Date variable in vba using sql query

Tags: date, datetime, vb6

I have a query in VB6:

```
"select plate_no from INFO where date_time between #07-10-2012 01:13:17# and #10/10/2012 11:30:25#"
```

My Access database table has the column with datatype Data/Time in general format.

How do I modify the query above to use variables like:

```
Public t1 As Date 
Public t2 As Date
```

Comment: Out of interest, is that date the 7th of October 2012 or the 10th of July 2012? (I believe most parsers will treat it as the former) I've updated the answer to be unambigious anyway.

Answer (score 4):

I'm doing it from memory, may have to tweak it to compile:

```
Public t1 as Date
Public t2 as Date

t1 = #10/07/2012 01:13:17# '7th of October 2012
t2 = #10/10/2012 11:30:25# '10th of October 2012

sql = "select plate_no from INFO where date_time between #" + Format(t1, "YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS") + "# and #" + Format(t2, "YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS") + "#"
```

Comment: @DanielCook Yeah I wondered - haven't used VB in years. But figured it would work, thanks.

Comment: @DanielCook Yes it should. The default date to string conversion is locale specific. the SQL libraries normally need an explicit format. I've also adjusted the date literals to be unambigious in both the VB code and the SQL. VB uses `mm/dd/yyyy` regardless of the locale and the `yyyy-mm-dd` in SQL is clear.

Comment: @Deanna You're right (which you already knew). I wasn't paying enough attention and thought this question was Access specific and forgot to consider different locales.